# How to copy value in one cell based on value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

See the image, I want to copy E5 to another cell based on E3 value. I just want copy single cell or single value. Its like "copy just E5 if E3 value = 13/6/2020".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKTAu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cell you need to copy `E5` to put this formula:

```
=IF(E3 = DATE(2020, 5, 13), E5, "")
```

If `E3` is 13/6/2020 then the value from `E5` will be placed in a new cell, otherwise an empty string - `""`.